# GroupPrincipal and PrincipalSearcher query using closest domain controller?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm using:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "somedomain.net");
var result = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, sid);
```

and am concerned about performance. I would like to specify the domain also.  Is there a way to specify both?

I know how to find the closest DC but I would like to use `GroupPrincipal and PrincipalSearcher`.

Is there a way to specific a specific domain controller?  Or, are PrincipalContext or FindByIdentity already doing that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quess I was missing the container parameter:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "SERVERNAME", "DC=somedomain,DC=net");
```